# Do DC current can be earthed?

Tags: batteries, dc, grounding

If I take a 12 V battery and connected its (+) terminal with the (+) wire of a load and connected the negative wire from the load to the ground (earthing).
I have heard that earthing absorbs current in AC system (Used as return path). Do it is same on DC.

Is this circuit be close or open? Please give reason for your statement.

Would the LED Glow or not?

Thanks in Advance,
Your response will be highly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Ok, there's a lot of problems with this question. 1) You haven't connected the battery (-) to anything. 2) A 15 Watt-hour LED doesn't make sense. 3) Where do you measure a 1.5 V difference? 4) The way you phrase it makes it look like a homework question. 5) No one is going to tell you "more about A/C & D/C systems" unless you tell exactly what you want to know.

Comment: What is the other terminal of the battery connected to? (The easy way to answer this question would be to include a schematic of your circuit: Edit your question and hit Ctrl-M to start the schematic editor)

Comment: Other terminal is left untouched.

Comment: You have edited the question, and it is still entirely unclear.

Comment: I calculated the Potential difference with a Digital Multimeter

Comment: WHAT does "My own made grounding" mean?

WHERE are you measuring "potential difference of 1.5 V"?  Between where and where?

WHY are you connecting the - side of the load to ground/earth? Why not simply connect it directly to the battery?

HOW is the - side of the battery connected?

Your question just raises more questions. We don't really know WHAT you are doing. And we don't know WHY you are doing it?  Please explain the larger picture of what you are trying to do.

Comment: I mean to say that made the earthing at my backyard myself

Comment: Ok. I am a new geek. If there's anything wrong please tell me.

Comment: Wait.. don't tell me you're using the actual earth as a ground return.. That would explain the problem. It is a very stupid idea, but it doesn't have to be a stupid question.

Comment: Forget about 12 V battery or LED. I just want to ask if I try to replace the negative terminal of a battery with a ground (which usually used as Neutral in A/C systems) will the circuit be complete.

Comment: No you can't, and it's only used as a neutral in A/C systems where you can't afford an extra cable. And we can't "forget" about the battery or LED because that's exactly what the question is about. If you want an answer, then write a good question, not filled with irrelevant details.

Comment: [Kirchhoff's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws) might offer some clarity: one side of your battery is not connected to anything, hence, how much current do you think could be flowing through it?

Comment: @uint128_t I think his battery is connected to ground. Literally. Which kinda sorta works (see for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-wire_earth_return), but _not_ with 12VDC.

Comment: Your circuit would seem complete if you earth battery -ve terminal too.
By the way, do this, what I just said. And find out.
I guess it will work. ;)

Comment: But I did so I won't need the Ground itself. I could simply attach the wire to the terminal. Same as you said

Comment: You try and see if this works yourself. The current wants to get from the positive of the power source to the negative of that SAME power source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your latest photo is the COMPLETE circuit, then you have NO path for any current to flow through the load.  If the - side of the battery is connected to nothing (as shown in your photo) then no current can flow.

It makes NO difference whether any part of the circuit is connected to ground.

> Would the circuit be complete or not?

No. The circuit is NOT complete.

> Please give reason for your statement.

You need a complete path (loop) for the current to connect from BOTH sides of the source (the battery) to the load.  You have only one side connected.

> I have heard that earthing pushes out current in AC system. Do it is same on DC.

That makes no sense. For AC or for DC.

> Would the LED Glow or not?

No

Comment: Actually a battery won't do WORK unless or until it's both terminals are connected with each other having a load in between.

Comment: Batteries only work when we connect both terminals so that +ve Voltage & -ve Voltage get meet at a Load where they get converted into any other energy. (i.e Light energy from LED Bulb

Comment: battery is 0. But if you test it you actually make a path and current starts flowing from positive electrode having P.D: +12 V through your Meter towards the negative electrode having P.D -12 V. But rather batteries are printed to be positive 12 V as negative voltage in battery doesn't count. Am I right? If not please tell me the right.

Comment: A circuit must have a COMPLETE path from the battery + to the load, and then from the other side of the load back to the - side of the battery. If you break any part of this loop path, no current will flow and you have an incomplete circuit. When you use your meter, the meter itself provides the current path. When you remove the meter, the circuit is broken and no current will flow.

Comment: But if I place any other type of DC source in place of a battery, would the circuit be complete?

Comment: The circuit will NOT be complete if there is not a continuous loop for current to flow. If you leave one side of the power source disconnected, it is NOT a complete circuit, no matter WHAT the source is.  This is an extremely simple concept. We don't understand what you are missing here?  Do you think that connecting something to "earth" has some magic properties? It does not.

Comment: I am thinking that connecting one end of circuit to earth will try to draw out current from the battery & hence the current will pass from the load leading it to glow and hence the circuit can be complete? Do it will happen?

Comment: No. The connection to the earth plays NO PART in your circuit. There is nothing magic about a connection to earth. If one side of your power supply is floating then you will NEVER have a complete circuit. By definition. Ground or no ground.